# Navigation icons load in layout.html, but not in fragment for apostrophe-headless api

Tags: headless, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I've created a fragment for apostrophe-headless, which loads my main navigation menu.

```
'apostrophe-pages': {
      restApi: true,
      apiTemplates: [ 'leftMenu']
},
```

This fragment has two functions:

- in *views/layout.html* I `{% include "apostrophe-pages:api/leftMenu.html" %}` it
- and I also pass it onto our angular app through **/api/v1/apostrophe-pages/?render=leftMenu.html**
  in that fragment, I build my menu, including a few navicons.

  ```
  {%- for tab in homeData._children -%}
     {% set imageURL = apos.attachments.url(apos.images.first(tab.navicon), { size: 'one-third' }) or null %}
      {{ apos.log(tab.navicon) }}
      <li><a href="/"><img src="{{ imageURL }}"></a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  ```

**PROBLEM:** These *tab.navicons* are not being loaded when this fragment is called through the API.

**views/layout.html** console.log of *tab.navicon*

```
_docId:"cjiqwpbjb00202zya1uf6wcm8"
_dotPath:"navicon"
_edit:true
items:Array(1) [Object]
type:"area"
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , 
__defineSetter__: , …}
```

**/api/v1/apostrophe-pages/?render=leftMenu.html** console.log of *tab.navicon*

```
items:Array(1) [Object]
type:"area"
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , 
__defineSetter__: , …}
```

Any thoughts?
Could it be a filters/depth issue?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible with `apostrophe-headless` in a single call. Both the root GET route that fetches the entire tree and the per-page GET route currently have `areas(false)` hardcoded for performance when loading children.

This could be remedied by adding an initially empty method that is given a chance to modify that cursor object before the query takes place. Then project-level overrides would be possible. That would require a pull request to apostrophe-headless but it wouldn't be a very difficult one.

In the meantime, the workaround is to make additional apostrophe-headless calls for each of the child pages. The response for the page itself will always load areas (and thus join with images, populating the data you are looking for). For performance you could cache these responses in your client code.

I have [opened a github issue on this](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless/issues/24).